# Where should react-thunk func go if no componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

Since React 16.3 has arrived, I am trying to refactor my code to use the new and preferred `static getDerivedStateFromProps()` but I this is what I currently have in my `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.chatId !== this.props.chatId) 
        this.subscribeChatMessages(nextChatId)  // a redux-thunk function 
}
```

Since static function cannot call anything from `this`, what should I do?

I can move the redux-thunk function to `shouldComponentUpdate`, but doesn't it seem wrong?

Comment: Can you share the `subscribeChatMessages(..)` definition?

Comment: standard code that will fetch something from the backend and dispatch the data once arrived async with the use of redux-thunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `subscribeChatMessages(..)` is a redux-thunk-action function that has a side-effect, you should put it in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (nextProps.chatId !== this.props.chatId) 
        this.subscribeChatMessages(nextChatId)  // a redux-thunk function 
}
```

Comment: As stated in the question, static function cannot call anything from `this` so the call will fail in `static getDerivedStateFromProps()`

Comment: Then there's one more reason you should use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`, as I mentioned at the end. I will edit my post.